# VSO Build definition to retrieve code from multiple repositories and multi-step build and reference

Tags: git, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We have a single Team Project in Visual Studio Online that makes use of multiple repos maintained by different development teams.

```
E.g.
Common repo - common framework, libraries
App1 repo - First application
App2 repo - Second application
```

Primary Desire

App1, App2 teams depend on the Common projects/assemblies for base functionality. We found that configuring Build definitions for VSO (within Visual Studio 2013) that it seems focused only on a single Git repository.

How is it possible to pull code sources from multiple repositories to perform a composite build? Compile the common projects, make assemblies available for reference by the dependent app projects, etc. Or even possibly pull out a specific version (tag) from the Common repo which dependents should be working on.

For now we kind of have explicitly pre-compiled and package the common assemblies into specific versions, which the dependent solutions then include as a fixed binary library asset within their own repositories.

Advanced Desire

The apps are in reality sub-systems to a grander system. How is it possible to have a single Build definition build the code from all these different repositories in a unified sequence?

Answer (score 3):

I'd tackle the problem in a different way.

Start by taking the compiled output of your common framework/library code and creating a NuGet package from them. Then reference that NuGet package in your App1 and App2 applications.

There's plenty of options to make the NuGet easy to consume, such as a private MyGet feed. MyGet also has a post about their [VSO integration](http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/05/12/Announcing-Visual-Studio-Online-integration.aspx) for example, however all you really need is a way for the common/framework nuget packages to be available for the other apps to consume.

As a note, this approach will also help with versioning and dependency management and takes away the need to have a staged build pipeline as you can build the framework and applications independently of each other.

Comment: this sounds nice, but doesn't actually answer the question